# Eagle DRC width errors on only power traces?

Tags: eaglecad

I am designing a circuit in EAGLE 6.4, and when running all DRCs (I have used OSHPark, SparkFun, and default), my power and ground traces come up as width errors. They are 10 mils wide, which is well within spec, and I have many other signal traces that are also 10 mils wide that do not show up as a width error.

Similarly, any power traces with vias show up as a drill error at the vias. However, vias on the signal traces are fine - and they are the same size!

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do HELP CLASS.  You probably have the power and ground traces assigned to a different class that requires wider traces.

Also, it's not clear what your picture is supposed to show us.  The single 2-pin SMD part in the picture seems to have a trace running to it from some odd layer other than the top.  Of course that won't connect.